# Drawing several images with canvas using off-screen rendering technique

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm trying to figure out a way to draw several images which are pulled from facebook and in a JSON data object which has become quite complex once I get them and do what I need to do before they're displayed.

The images are profile pics, that need to be cropped using ctx.clip() to make them circles, and then a ring is drawn on top to make them have different color borders based on the type of friend or w/e. That's all set, works fine. Where I'm getting stuck is, were using this to create a visualization of the data and fb pics we pull, http://thejit.org, and it is animating the visual when it loads right. So when these circular pics are drawn to the canvas, there are like 500 times that ctx.drawImage() is called and it's stupid. What needs to be done is get the data, create a temp canvas and ctx, draw each image to them, and then draw those canvases to the main canvas, THEN run the animation.

make sense?

any tips or ideas about how to go about doing that?

Comment: So it sounds like you have a good handle on the process to take. What's the question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the issue here is likely caused by the slowness of facebook and how damn long it takes for firefox versions 6 and lower to make the connection, and return the data needed, my case profile images.

I also get returned this for each image I request too, only in firefox idk why, but seems to have to do with the secure connection stuff and hacking blah, images, facebook. blah...

**graph.facebook.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555**

The Net firebug tab shows that each image requested takes 4.0 - 4.12 seconds to connect and be returned. That's retarded... Srsly? What's the effin reason for that, facebook is sucky, or something. It's not that slow to request images from other sites when they're dynamic and stuff. blargghh!!

I did at one point manage to make some crazy insane tweaky hack thing that somehow got it to work, but i don't know what it was, and must have undid it cuz it's no longer working... :(

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're describing is covered in the *Pre-render to an Off-screen Canvas* section of this document: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/#toc-pre-render

You can pass a canvas to the `canvas.drawImage()` function. This allows you to create an off-screen canvas using `document.createElement("canvas")`, perform some drawing operations, and then write the image contents of that canvas to your primary (on-screen) canvas.

Comment: yeah, i know that. i had it working actually. 'almost'. just not in firefox. it worked in chrome though. what i'm having difficulty with is loading the images and drawing them off-screen, image.onload = function() { tmpCtx.drawImage(src,0,0)}
then drawing those contexts to the main canvas context at the node position so they will animate.
ctx.drawImage(tmpCtx,nodePosition,nodePosition)
so, i guess i just need to draw the images first to the tempCtx's first i guess.